# How do you replace multiple characters from a single value using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove the special characters in a phone number. Specifically the parenthesis. When I run this with only one of the parenthesis it works fine, but whenever I attempt to add a second string to replace it only does the first one. This is what I am using.

```
  df['phoneNumber'] = df['phoneNumber'].str.replace({'(':'',')':''}), regex=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `replace` method takes two parameter, a pattern and a replacement.  You can pass it a regex pattern that finds open and closed parenthesis and replaces them with nothing using:

```
df.phoneNumber.str.replace('[\(\)]', '')
```

Comment: Thank you James, for anyone that is looking at this later, this is the exact code I used. 
`df['phoneNumber'] = df['phoneNumber'].str.replace('[\(\)]', '')`

Answer (score 2):

```
df.phoneNumber.str.replace('(', '').str.replace(')', '')
```

or

```
df.phoneNumber.apply(lambda s: ''.join(c for c in s if c not in {'(', ')'}))
```